# Sobolev inequality in 1 dimension

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{T}^{1})$ with periodic boundary conditions. Then the following Sobolev inequality (in one dimension) holds:

$$ \|u\|_{L^{\infty}} \le C\|u\|_{W^{1,2}}. $$
I have read somewhere that in such a setting, we have by the Sobolev inequality that

$$\|u\|_{L^{\infty}} \le \|u\|_{L^{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\|\partial_{x} u\|_{L^{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}+ \|u\|_{L^{2}},$$ but I cannot see how this follows. The best I can do is
\begin{aligned}\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}  &\le C\|u\|_{W^{1,2}} = C(\|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}+\|\partial_{x}u\|_{L^{2}}^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&\le C(\|u\|_{L^{2}} + \|\partial_{x}u\|_{L^{2}}) \\
&= C(\|u\|_{L^{2}} + \|\partial_{x}u\|_{L^{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\|\partial_{x}u\|_{L^{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}). \end{aligned}

Are they perhaps using something else other than the inequality I mentioned? I am unable to link the mentioned paper.

Comment: Which of these inequalities are you interested in? It is not clear to me, what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u$ be smooth. Then we have
$$
u(t)^2 = u(s)^2 +2\int_s^t u(x)u'(x)dx,
$$
which implies
$$
u(t)^2 \le u(s)^2 + 2\|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}\|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)}.
$$
Integrating wrt $s\in (0,1)$ yields
$$
u(t)^2 \le \|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 + 2\|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}\|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)},
$$
now take the maximum wrt $t$, to get
$$
\|u\|_{L^\infty}^2 \le \|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 + 2\|u\|_{L^2(0,1)}\|u'\|_{L^2(0,1)}.
$$
This holds for smooth $u$, and by density, for all $u\in W^{1,2}$.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. But shouldn't there be a 2 in front of the integral in the first line? Because integration by parts will give you that $$2 \int_{s}^{t} uu' ~dx = u(t)^{2}-u(s)^{2}$$

Comment: yes, thanks, will correct.